# Group attachments in single email instead of creating multiple separate emails to the same email address

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have a table of data.

- Column B is email address
- Column C is the first 6 digits of file name
- Column J is Directorate or Place
- Column N is file path

I select files using the first 6 digits of the file name.

My macro will search the Directory/path and bring back the relevant file. If it doesn't find a file, it doesn't create an email.

I get duplicate emails for different reports. So the same person, but a separate report.

I want if the next row down has the same values in column B (email address) and column J (Directorate or Place) then include this new file within the existing email. i.e. don't make a new email for the same person. Group them together.

Feel free to ignore my efforts at doing this where it states 'TESTING' in comments.

```vb
Sub MailerMACRO()
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
Set rng = Worksheets("STATIC COPY OF DIST").Range("N3:N7")  'This is where folder paths are
For Each cell In rng 'For each cell in the above range
    Dim SendAccount As String 'reference the email address as text
    Dim CostCentre As String ' reference the first 6 digits of the file name as text
    Dim Directz As String
    Dim Namez As String
    
    Namez = Split(cell.Offset(0, -13).Value, " ")(0) ' Just take the first name of the individual for email
    CostCentre = cell.Offset(0, -11).Value '(look 11 columns to the left of column N, AKA column C)
    Directz = StrConv((cell.Offset(0, -4).Value), vbProperCase) 'Change the directorate name from block capitals to proper case
       
    Path = cell.Value 'What is the file path from ccell in column N
    If Path <> "" Then ' If its not blank, then what
 
        EmailAdd = cell.Offset(0, -12).Value 'Get the email from column B, 12 columns to the left of column N
        ClientFile = Dir(Path & CostCentre & "*.*") 'Look into the file path and search using the first 6 digits shown as 'Cust Digits'
    
        If ClientFile = "" Then GoTo DisBit 'If there's no staff list then skip to the end.
        'TESTING THIS AGAIN
       ' If cell.Offset(-1, -12).Value = EmailAdd And StrConv((cell.Offset(-1, -4).Value), vbProperCase) = Directo Then GoTo Chicago
        'TESTING THIS AGAIN
         
        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 'Email setup via outlook
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(o)
        With OutMail
            .Subject = Range("B1").Value & " - " & Directz & " - Staff Lists" 'value in cell B1 and "Staff Lists" as a formulae
            .to = EmailAdd
            .SentOnBehalfOfName = "nth-tr.financialmanagement@nhs.net" ' Send via FM mailbox.
            .Body = "Hi " & Namez & "," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Please find attached your Staff Lists to accompany your Monthly Financial Statements/Reports." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Kind Regards," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Financial Management Team" ' & .Body
            .Display
            
'TESTING THIS ELEMENT
'Chicago:
            Do While ClientFile <> ""
                If Len(ClientFile) > 0 Then
                    AttachFile = Path & ClientFile
                    .Attachments.Add (AttachFile)
                End If
                ClientFile = Dir
            Loop
        
        End With
    End If
DisBit:
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

My data table has around 300 rows with multiple duplicates. I can sort them so that my idea may work.

Answer (score 0):

First manually sort by Name/Email Address and Directorate

```vb
Option Explicit ' Consider this mandatory
' Tools | Options | Editor tab
' Require Variable Declaration
' If desperate declare as Variant

Sub MailerMACRO()

'  First manually sort by Name/Email Address and Directorate

'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim Rng As Range
Dim cell As Range

Dim Path As String
Dim EmailAdd As String
Dim ClientFile As String
Dim AttachFile As String

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

Dim SendAccount As String   ' email address
Dim CostCentre As String    ' first 6 digits of the file name
Dim Directz As String
Dim Namez As String

Dim NamezPrior As String
NamezPrior = ""

Dim DirectzPrior As String
DirectzPrior = ""

Dim CostCentrePrior As String
CostCentrePrior = ""

Set Rng = Worksheets("STATIC COPY OF DIST").Range("N3:N7")  'This is where folder paths are

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 'Email setup via outlook

For Each cell In Rng 'For each cell in the above range

    Debug.Print
    Debug.Print "NamezPrior..: " & NamezPrior
    Namez = Split(cell.Offset(0, -13).Value, " ")(0) ' Just take the first name of the individual for email
    Debug.Print "Namez.......: " & Namez
    
    CostCentre = cell.Offset(0, -11).Value '(look 11 columns to the left of column N, AKA column C)
    Debug.Print "CostCentre..: " & CostCentre
    
    Debug.Print "DirectzPrior: " & DirectzPrior
    Directz = StrConv((cell.Offset(0, -4).Value), vbProperCase) 'Change the D name from block capitals to proper case
    Debug.Print "Directz.....: " & Directz
    
    Path = cell.Value 'What is the file path from cell in column N
    Debug.Print "Path........: " & Path
    
    If Path <> "" Then
        
        EmailAdd = cell.Offset(0, -12).Value 'Get the email from column B, 12 columns to the left of column N
        Debug.Print "EmailAdd....: " & EmailAdd
        
        Debug.Print "Path & CostCentre: " & Path & CostCentre & "*.*"
        ClientFile = Dir(Path & CostCentre & "*.*") 'Look into the file path and search using the first 6 digits shown as 'Cust Digits'
        Debug.Print "ClientFile..: " & ClientFile
        
        If ClientFile <> "" Then
        
            If Namez <> NamezPrior Then
            
                Debug.Print
                Debug.Print "Namez <> NamezPrior"
                Debug.Print "New mail"
                
                Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
                OutMail.Display
                
                With OutMail
                    .Subject = Range("B1").Value & " - " & Directz & " - Staff Lists" 'value in cell B1 and "Staff Lists" as a formulae
                    .to = EmailAdd
                    .SentOnBehalfOfName = "nth-tr.financialmanagement@nhs.net" ' Send via FM mailbox.
        
                    .Body = "Hi " & Namez & "," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                      "Please find attached your Staff Lists to accompany your Monthly Financial Statements/Reports." & _
                      vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Kind Regards," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Financial Management Team" ' & .Body
                      
                    .Display
                    
                    Do While ClientFile <> ""
                        If Len(ClientFile) > 0 Then
                            AttachFile = Path & ClientFile
                            .Attachments.Add (AttachFile)
                        End If
                        ClientFile = Dir
                    Loop
                    
                End With
                            
            ElseIf Directz <> DirectzPrior Then
                
                Debug.Print
                Debug.Print "Directz <> DirectzPrior"
                Debug.Print "New mail"
                
                Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
                    
                With OutMail
                    .Subject = Range("B1").Value & " - " & Directz & " - Staff Lists" 'value in cell B1 and "Staff Lists" as a formulae
                    .to = EmailAdd
                    .SentOnBehalfOfName = "nth-tr.financialmanagement@nhs.net" ' Send via FM mailbox.
                    .Body = "Hi " & Namez & "," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                      "Please find attached your Staff Lists to accompany your Monthly Financial Statements/Reports." & _
                      vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Kind Regards," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Financial Management Team" ' & .Body
                    .Display
                    
                    Do While ClientFile <> ""
                        If Len(ClientFile) > 0 Then
                            AttachFile = Path & ClientFile
                            .Attachments.Add (AttachFile)
                        End If
                        ClientFile = Dir
                    Loop
                        
                End With
                
            Else ' Directz = DirectzPrior
                
                Debug.Print
                Debug.Print "Directz = DirectzPrior"
                Debug.Print "Existing mail"
                
                With OutMail
                    Do While ClientFile <> ""
                        If Len(ClientFile) > 0 Then
                            AttachFile = Path & ClientFile
                            .Attachments.Add (AttachFile)
                        End If
                        ClientFile = Dir
                    Loop
                End With
            End If
            
        Else    ' ClientFile = "" - no staff list
    
            'No action
            Debug.Print
            Debug.Print "No staff list. No action."
    
        End If
        
    End If
    
    NamezPrior = Namez
    DirectzPrior = Directz

Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Debug.Print "Done."

End Sub
```